# Why do I get 'Undefined offset: 0'?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm develop a website and it looks fine.
Then I turned on debugging to see if I had any errors, and I get this message:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in I:\path\to\file\MyFile.class.php on line 105
```

On that line you will find the following code:

```
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $result[0]; // line 105
```

If I do a `print_r(result)` I get the following result:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 3721
        [parentID] =>
    )
)
Array (
)
```

As you can see the result contains twoarrays. The first one has data, the second one has no data. I've never seen `print_r` output two arrays like this. I'm guessing it's the second one causing me the problems.

Can anyone advice me of why that second array sneaks in?

**VAR dump**

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => string '3721' (length=4)
      'parentID' => null
array
  empty
```

Comment: "As you can see the result contains twoarrays." --- wrong. As we can see - there are two different arrays print_r'ed

Comment: Could you please post a result from `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: It actually can't "sneak in", there must be something wrong. Maybe you call `print_r` two times in your code? What is the output of `var_dump($result);`?

Comment: You should always turn on debugging, *then* develop - in that order.

Comment: @Niko, @duri - See my var dump above. But is the empty array the cause of my `undefined offset` error?

Comment: Are you calling that code twice? On the second call you seem to get an empty result, see yi_H's answer below for details why this causes the notice.

Comment: Make sure you `exit` after calling `var_dump()` or you may end up with two or more dumps.

Comment: @zerkms - I've searched my prosject and the only other place I use `print_r`, is to display error info - ` print_r($this->db->errorInfo());`

Comment: @Wesley Murch - you are right. Adding `exit` after `print_r` does not output the empty array. Does that mean my query might be running twice and that's why I get the error msg?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. The second one must be giving you the error. In any case, you should make sure the array index exists before trying to access it if you want to avoid notices, just get in the habit.

Comment: @Wesley Murch - The function is run twise. That's why it's outputting data, but at the same time give me the error message. Thanks, you "solved" my problem :)

Answer (score 5):

You fetch all records matching the query. If there are *no* records it will return an empty array. Obviously there is no `0` element in an empty array.

Comment: as you can see, records are returned. The first array contains another array with data. Giving you +1 since this shouldn't be downvoted.

Comment: no, on the second call no records are returned. check the backtrace to see where and how you call it the second time.