# Undefined offset: 0 in php

Tags: php

I wrote a function in php that return all the values in the table. but it has a problem with my code. when i run this function in else it says that error "Undefined offset: 0" So if any one have any idea about this please let me know what it's and how can i fix it 
thank you

```
//Select All function
protected function selectAll($action, $tablename, $where = array()){
    try{
        $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("{$action} FROM {$tablename} WHERE {$where[0]} {$where[1]} ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $where[2]);
        $query->execute();
        $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $result[0];
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your $where array populated with data? This will always fail if the where array is empty. Also if $result is empty ofc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7460639/why-do-i-get-undefined-offset-0

Comment: Maybe there were no rows found?

Comment: @ViPiN I guess you meant `var_dump`? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a check to make sure `$where` array always contains atleast 2 elements.
Also use `fetch()` to query for just one row.

Example:

```
$result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // One result
```

Your solution:

```
protected function selectAll($action, $tablename, $where = array()){

  try{

    if( !count( $where ) < 2) {
      throw new PDOException( 'Invalid where filter' );
    }

    $query = $this->_pdo->prepare("{$action} FROM {$tablename} WHERE {$where[0]} {$where[1]} ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $where[2]);
    $query->execute();

    // More than one result
    $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    return $result;

  }
  catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: please let me know
what do you mean by %where array contains 2 elements in always
if

Comment: @ChathuraBuddika since your function requires two elements from the `$where` array, we need a check to make sure of that using the `count()` function